# Making SwiftUI app Scriptable with AppleScript and Javascript JXA

Tags: swift, applescript, macos-big-sur, appleevents, sdef

Please note I have carefully followed [How to implement AppleScript support in a Swift MacOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162546/how-to-implement-applescript-support-in-a-swift-macos-app) - however this is not working for me.  I assume it's out of date.

---

After following a variety of documentation, guides, examples, I'm stuck trying to get AppleScript / Javascript support working in a SwiftUI app. (in Macos Big Sur, to begin with.)

The main problem seems to be that all documentation, examples, etc. are out of date.

I could pose this question as being about Swift 5 + `AppDelegate` instead of SwiftUI and I'd be in the same pickle.

So here's what I have so far...

- Info.plist - (absent in SwiftUI) added with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>OSAScriptingDefinition</key>
    <string>Progression.sdef</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- Progression.entitlements to allow scripting. (Sandbox is switched off too.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <false/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- I've then created what I hope is a working `Progression.sdef` scripting definition file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary title="Progression Terminology">
    <suite name="Progression Suite" code="PrgN" description="Progression scripting classes and commands.">
        <command name="progress" code="proGress">
            <cocoa class="Progression.ProgressCommand"/>
        </command>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

- `ProgressCommand` in the SwiftUI app.

```
import Foundation
@objc class ProgressCommand: NSScriptCommand {
    @objc override func performDefaultImplementation() -> Any? {
        print("Called")
        return nil
    }
}
```

- I can load the app, and detect the sdef in *ScriptEditor > Open Dictionary...*
- In an AppleScript I can call quit on the app (although TBH I haven't tested to see if this works if I pull all the scripting items out.):

```
tell application "Progression"
  quit
end tell
```

- In AppleScript if I call `progress` it seems to recognize the command, although I'm not sure if it's getting past the `.sdef` level ... because it fails with:

```
tell application "Progression"
  progress
end tell
```

```
error "Progression got an error: Can’t continue progress." number -1708
```

At this point I'm stuck for a couple of days.

#### Edit: I found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37202803/311660 although adding the code to the SwiftUI App doesn't work.

Thankfully there is a project & code supplied (using the older NSAppDelegate Style.) which works standalone.

If I can't get a working answer for pure SwiftUI, I'll just re-implement the app using `NSAppDelegate`, at the end of the day I just need a working link to ApppleScript.

The question remains, is this possible in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement AppleScript support in a Swift MacOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162546/how-to-implement-applescript-support-in-a-swift-macos-app)

Comment: It does not, if you look carefully, I'm pretty much doing what's described there. If it's   google-able  I've probably already iterated over it.   I've attempted to verify my solution by studying the code for iTerm2 which has extensive AppleScript support. (Although it's deprecated  an  ObjC specific.)  That reminds, I should note that Macos  Big Sur is in use here.

Comment: I also need to show the .entitlements are set. / done

Comment: @Willeke - you can go ahead and remove  your vote to close.

Comment: The answer says "Turns out App.ScriptableApplicationCommand is essential. ScriptableApplicationCommand alone doesn't do a thing.". Have you tried this?

Comment: I have, I updated the .sdef in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37202803/311660 - The code provided with this answer does work.  I'll work it into my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37202803/311660 solves this problem, it works fine with SwiftUI.

The problem in my code is the name of my command.

```xml
<command name="progress" code="progress">
```

[`progress`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html) is a reserved word [(used for `progress indicator`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html), changing it to `foobar` in my example code, fixes the issue.

This [project](https://github.com/ocodo/progression) was built to show how to use SwiftUI with AppleScript.